# Labeling in ggplot2 / group factor

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, categorical-data

I have the following data:

```
 data.plot <- data.frame (x.plot=c(-1.1934, 1.2809,-1.1934, 1.2809 ), y.plot=c(2.4979,2.3664, 2.4606,2.6113), axis=c("Low","Low", "High", "High"))
```

I want to create a plot with two lines:

1. Line 1: X= x.plot, Y=y1.plot
2. Line 2: x=x.plot, Y=y2.plot
3. Label of Y-Axis: Stress
4. Label of X-Axis: two labels, "low" should be labeled at position x=-1.1934 and "high" should be labeled at position x=1.2809
5. Legend: in a separate box, with the heading "Treatment A" indicating that Line 1 is "low" and Line 2 is "high"

I have gotten so far:

```
ggplot(data.plot, aes(x=factor(x.plot), y=y.plot, linetype=axis, group=axis)) + geom_line()
```

How do I change the labels? Need some help on points 3, 4 and 5 from above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put labels on a ggplot, you need to add the labs attribute, like:

```
ggplot(...) + geom_line() + labs(y="Stress",linetype="Treatment A")
```

Two put two different x-axis labels I think you should add something like

```
annotate(geom="text",x=...,y=...,label="your text")
```

into your plot, but I'm not sure.